# Binding of DataGrid column header to a list of String or Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm new to WPF. I'm developing an application using MVVM. I need to build a datagrid in which column headers should bind to a List or collection. And the number of columns should be equal to the number of elements in the list with respective headers as List elements.

I have this sample code available from MSDN.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Binding-of-DataGrid-column-73f80f68/sourcecode?fileId=74132&pathId=179795492

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeaderNameText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Data data = new Data();
        data.HeaderNameText = "Header2";
        data.Items = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2" };

        this.DataContext = data;
    }
}
```

Here HeaderNameText is a string, I need it to be a List to generate Column with each Header as a element of the list.

I have searched much and couldn't find anything usefull

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `DataGridColumn.Header` property, you should use the [`DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.headertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeaderNameText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm not sure if that will do what you want really, because the number of items in the `Items` collection will affect the number of rows that the `DataGrid` has and *not* the number of columns.